# Generate summary with counts of joiners, leavers and running count of users

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, cumulative-sum, running-count

I have a table with a large number of events that have happened, like the following:

| ts | event |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-09 19:20:19 UTC | joined |
| 2023-01-16 09:34:02 UTC | joined |
| 2022-08-19 10:02:44 UTC | left |
| 2022-10-06 10:11:12 UTC | joined |
| 2021-10-06 10:11:13 UTC | left |

Each event involves either a "joiner" or a "leaver", with a TIMESTAMP "ts" associated. I need to create a report that gives joiners, leavers and total users for each month. The total users would be a running total of the number of users, like the following:

| Year | Month | Joiners | Leavers | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 03 | 50 | 0 | 50 |
| 2023 | 04 | 5 | 1 | 54 |
| 2023 | 05 | 30 | 10 | 74 |
| 2023 | 06 | 10 | 5 | 79 |

I need to compute:

- count for "*Joiners*", namely the number of "joined" events that happened in the month,
- count for "*Leavers*", which would be the number of "left" events that happened in the month
- "Total", as a running total number of joined users minus left users (if 10 people joined and 2 people left, then the actual total number of people would be 8; if 10 more people joined next month and 0 people left then the Total needs to be 18 in the next month)

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts) year,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts) month,
       event,
       COUNT(event) AS total,
       SUM(COUNT(event)) OVER(ORDER BY event) AS running_total
FROM `data.events`
GROUP BY year, month, event
ORDER BY year ASC, month ASC, event ASC
```

This is the closest that I've achieved so far with a very basic understanding of SQL, however it's not what I was aiming for. I can't get the COUNT or SUM running total to work.

Any help that could point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall first generate your two aggregated values "*Joiners*" and "*Leavers*" with conditional aggregation, then use a running sum on `Joiners-Leavers`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts) year,
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts) month,
           SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'joined' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS Joiners,
           SUM(CASE WHEN event = 'left'   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS Leavers
    FROM `data.events`
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts),
             EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts)
)
SELECT cte.*, 
       SUM(Joiners-Leavers) OVER(ORDER BY year, month) AS Total
FROM cte 
ORDER BY year, month
```

Comment: this line is creating negative total values `SUM(Joiners-Leavers) OVER(ORDER BY year, month) AS Total`

Comment: Yeah it should: here we want to know the net amount of users. If there are more users leaving than coming, the net will be negative.

Comment: i definitely have a problem with understanding the problem correctly, looks good @lemon

Comment: @zhiguang and lemon. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question and help me out, I really appreciate the help. I'm a novice SQL and BigQuery user myself and I know how hard it can be to understand the question and work through the problem. Sorry, if the question wasn't totally clear.

Comment: We've all had issues understanding problems when we were novice about anything, and I went myself through that as well, it's part of the journey. Learning and time can help improve through it though.